# django-taggit: Is there a way to produce less db queries?

Tags: django, django-taggit

Say I have a model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

When I iterate over Entry.objects.all() in a template, entry.tags.all produces one more query to the database. Is it possible to reduce queries number? Using something like select_related() (I know it won't work, since django-taggit uses manytomany relation, but I am sure there should be a way to select all entries with related tags in 1 hit)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django-taggit prefetch\_related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926036/django-taggit-prefetch-related), or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204511/optimize-django-query-to-pull-foreign-key-and-django-taggit-relationship

Answer (score 3):

From Django 1.4 onward, you can use `prefetch_related` to retrieve one-to-many relations on a queryset in a single query. Unfortunately this doesn't work brilliantly with django-taggit, because the 'tags' property is a manager rather than a true relation, and so prefetch_related can't make sense of it. Instead, you need to follow the tagged_items relation:

`entries = Entry.objects.prefetch_related('tagged_items__tag')`

You then need to go through some similar contortions in the template code to access the prefetched tags, because `entry.tags.all` will run another query rather than making use of the prefetch:

```
{% for tagged_item in entry.tagged_items %}
    <li>{{ tagged_item.tag.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just a note - this caused a GenericRelatedObjectManager error for me. I changed `entry.tagged_items` to `entry.tagged_items.all` and it worked, but not with any improvement in SQL queries over the original code. Confused here.

Comment: django-taggit now supports prefetch_related('tags') since v0.11 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21670809/20198

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Select Reverse](http://code.google.com/p/django-selectreverse/) it's designed to grab the entirity of a many2many relationship with a single query.